# highcharts render black on ajax refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

yesterday i upgraded my highcharts.js file from the last V.2 file to the latest 3.0 file. Since i upgraded my file, when i refresh my page via an ajax call, all the charts display correct except they render black! I even downgraded my jquery version from 1.9.1 to 1.8.2(the version they use in their examples). I do not get any javascript errors.

Please help, this only happens on pie charts and stacked horizontal bar charts, all other charts seem to work fine?

Comment: Some example code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no example needed. it is the standard highcharts code.
I found a solution to the problem anyway just now.

When you init the chart just add the 'colors: [array]' to the options. this will resolve the black.